# soapUI can't access Internet.

Tags: proxy, offline, soapui

Hello I just downloaded soapUI and see this message after starting the app:

You're getting this message since your computer is offline and soapUI can't access Internet. Without Internet connection you might experience some issues when doing Web Service Testing.

I am using wireless connection to connect to the internet.

Comment: If you are asking the reason you get this message, please firstly be sure that you can connect to internet and then check if you are using proxy, if so you need to update soapUI proxy settings. (file > preferences > Proxy Settings )

Answer (score 1):

It will not affect anything, check you should be able to use SOAPUI, rest all features.

There was an ongoing issue in SOAPUI which is being reported multiple times, but looked like it appears again

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Pro/Starter-page-is-showing-that-computer-is-offline/td-p/28341

Answer (score 0):

Check your local firewall rules, if they are OK then configure SOAPUI with your WiFi [proxy settings](http://www.soapui.org/Working-with-soapUI/preferences.html#Proxy%20Settings%20Tab)